# Display Soft Keyboard Programmatically - not working

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have a togglebutton in my screen. If I click on this button, I need a keyboard to show up on the screen. This is the code I have right now, but it doesnt display the keyboard as expected :(

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        keyboard = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
        keyboard.setOnClickListener(displayKeyboard);
}

 OnClickListener displayKeyboard = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(client == null)
                   return;
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
            if(on){ // show keyboard
                System.out.println("Togglebutton is ON");
                keyboard.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.showSoftInput(keyboard, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
            else{ // hide keyboard
                System.out.println("Togglebutton is OFF");
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(keyboard.getWindowToken(), 0);          }
        }
    };
```

When I click the keyboard togglebutton, I see in LogCat that it goes into the if/else block, but otherwise doesnt display any keyboard on screen. can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `showSoftInput` you are trying to focus your `keyboard` button and to start sending keyboard events to it, but it is not focusable. Make it focusable like this (in your `onCreate`):

```
keyboard.setFocusable(true);
keyboard.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (In UTILITY class):

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

     public static void showSoftKeyboard(Activity activity, View focusedView)
     {
         InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
     }
```